# Storing a media(image,audio) on Amazon s3 and retrieving and showing it on browser

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, amazon-s3

I am new to `jsp` and `s3` . I am trying to solve a problem which is:

I need to save some media file say some kind of Images on s3 which I am doing by using `s3client.putObject` function of `AmazonS3`. From here I am getting the url of s3.

url is like  `https://abc.s3.amazonaws.com/18463/doc/xyz_1.jpg`.

From some other part of project now I need to get the object and render it to browser. I am not able to solve this issue. How will I get the s3Object and render it in the form of Image.

I have tried to solve it by using `StreamingOutput` . I am getting the inputstream. but it is something which is weird. generally when the base64 format of image stream is appended with `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ escape(result)>` it converts into the image format. but this is not happening in this scenario.

I am totally clueless how can I achieve the solution.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you visit your object URL in your web browser?

Comment: It shows following error:

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>08B0163E778A3E02</RequestId>
<HostId>
eVjoYhG8AI4nlzHNoPvEV8f9vwhgzGtsLxs2eFr0I2jsqF0RVXi2bCiNZ4b9LWUVtdlMcIcvjQw=
</HostId>
</Error>